# How to set "VM options" from IDEA to Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

For work-around I had to add to VM options in Run Configurations in Intellij IDEA, like on this screenshot: http://imagesup.net/?di=0137113095013

But how I could set this option on the appengine server? I found nothing similar in appengine.google.com/settings

I'm uploading my project in IDEA (Tools->Upload App Engine Application), may be there some settings to upload this VM options too.

Many thanks in advance, Alex

Comment: I'm sorry, this is impossible of course.

Comment: why do you think you need this?

Comment: There was some problem with persistence, that was fixed by such a work-around. I thought that there is no other ways to live with it other than to set this flag. But I found a little mistake, and now it's all fine.